# чтение строки в цикле->поиск фразы CMD/BAT

Tags: cmd, bat

Нужно в цикле открывать файл(файл в это время может пополняться данными) до тех пор пока на найдена нужная строка, и пока не найдена фраза показывать индикатор загрузки
Пробовал по разному, не получается

```
r /f %%i in ('findstr /v ^# myfiletxt') do (
  find "fraza"
) %%i
```

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку вот так:

```
@echo off
echo.
:cycle
for /f %%i in ('findstr /M /C:"Искомый Текст" c:\folder\filename.log') do (
  goto done
)
type x:\folder\symbol.txt
goto cycle
:done
```

Файл x:\folder\symbol.txt должен существовать и содержать ровно 1 байт того символа, которым будет рисоваться прогрессор. Например, звёздочка... А скорость бега прогрессора будет определяться исключительно скоростью проверки файла на нужную (под)строку. И скорее всего это будет ОЧЕНЬ быстро - так что перед `goto cycle` можно изобрести принудительную паузу на секунду, а то и на две...

Если есть желание, можно подсчитывать нарисованные символы, и по достижении 79 отправлять другой файл, c единственным символом LF.

Comment: Спасибо вам, но создал я допустим символ *, и запускаю bat и рисует бесконечные строки звёздочек... то есть зацикливание..